# EGOPhotoViewer: gesture not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm using the [EGOPhotoViewer](https://github.com/enormego/PhotoViewer) library for displaying photos in my iOS 5 App. Many of the galleries are working fine, but some of they have an issue. Please see this video on Vimeo:
http://vimeo.com/34300336.

As you can see, on the fifth image, a swipe no longer brings me to the next image. Does anybody know how to fix this issue in EGOPhotoViewer?

Please tell me if you need further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the *EGOPhotoScrollView.m* I changed the property `scrollEnabled` to NO, which seems to work for me. But I do not know what impact this could cause.